# bbPress css - theme has hidden breadcrumb

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bbpress

I have installed bbPress in my website and my theme override some bbPress css which I do not want.

The forum breadcrumb is hidden with the following code:

```
div.bbp-breadcrumb, div.bbp-topic-tags {
    font-size: 12px;
}
bbpress.css?ver….5.14-6684:404
div.bbp-breadcrumb {
    float: left;
}
vlog-bbpress.css?ver=1.8.1:335
.bbp-breadcrumb {
    display: none !important;
```

As you can see in the picture the CSS comes from two different files:

> bbpress.css
>   vlog-bbpress.css

[image: Screenshot]

Somehow the rendering seems to override bbpress.css.

- What code should I use to make the breadcrumb visible?
- Having installed a plugin (Simple Custom CSS) to write custom css, what should I write there in order to have the forum breadcrumb visible?

Please look at the real website here http://italiancrypto.it/forums/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breadcrumb is hidden by:

```
.bbp-breadcrumb {
    display: none !important;
}
```

What you see is that it is addressed by one class, and an `!important`. One class isn't a problem, but `!important` is (and is generally viewed as bad practice).

The easiest way to overcome this, is by addressing the same `bbp-breadcrumb` with an extra class, that's above it. For example:

```
.entry-content .bbp-breadcrumb {
    display: block !important;
}
```

You could also use the above ID of `bbpress-forum`, but that is generally viewed as bad practice as well. Then again, desperate times call for desperate measures ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try add an id to the class .bbp-breadcrumb with JS

```
document.querySelector('div.bbp-breadcrumb').id = 'breadcrumb';
```

this will add the id to the element, then in your css use

```
#breadcrumb {display:block !important;}
```

since the id takes precedence over class I think this should work.